# Sleep in for loop to create smooth effect

Tags: c#

I'd like to create a for loop that will slowly change the shape of my form over the course of a second so as to create a smooth effect. Using the code below, I get an error reading 'Then name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context'. Can anybody help me out?

```
for (var i = 1; i > 221; i++ )
{
    Form1.ActiveForm.Height += 1;
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(4.5);
}
```

Comment: add using System.Threading; and give sleep a miliseconds long value

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` should not be ever done on a UI thread. Switch to a `Timer` or even better WPF which has support for smooth [animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312(v=vs.110).aspx) when doing operations like resizing or moving.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll switch over to using a Timer instead.

Comment: Both Sleep() and DoEvents() are a bad idea. Timers have ~20ms resolution, as does Sleep().

Comment: Henk is correct, this is absolutely the wrong way to solve this problem. It is a *common* way to solve the problem, but a bad programming practice in a great many ways. In particular, if you do not understand why DoEvents causes re-entrancy errors, you should not be using it.  And you hired that thread to do work for you; don't pay it to sleep.

Comment: "Programmers who use `DoEvents` don't understand how it works.  Programmers who understand how it works, never use it." --Internet quote

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad idea to sleep in the GUI thread, as this inhibits the normal event processing code that, e.g., keeps the GUI painted and keeps the GUI controls responsive.  Instead, use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` with the same interval for which you would otherwise sleep and do your work in an event handler for `Timer.Tick`.

**Edit:** I just noticed that your code calls `Application.DoEvents()`, which mitigates the UI freezing problem but has its own sets of gotchas.

Answer (score 2):

If you are very sure about using animation in your programs and if it is an important part thereof I think it is better to spend some time learning the animation system of WPF.

An example of it can be found here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23257/Beginner-s-WPF-Animation-Tutorial

Showing you the ropes of it, is a bit difficult withing the boundaries of an answer like this.

Some advice though, if you use animations and also some parts of the code are doing some long running operation while the animation is running, make 100% sure that your long running operation is being performed on a background thread and not the GUI thread because the animations are already running on the GUI thread. Failing to do so would not yield the expected results.

Possible solutions to this problem are the use of async and await if you are up to it, the backgroundworker, or classic threads. Personally I try to use async and await. But if you already have to learn WPF and also async and await, you have quite some catching up to do.

On the other hand if you just want a fancy movement without any other logic, you'll find that WPF is really quick to get you going.

Btw do it right and you don't need any thread.sleep or doevent kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make sure you have imported System.Threading at the top of your file, or change your code to:

`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4);`

The Sleep method takes an integer or a Timespan, so if you really want a 4.5ms sleep interval try:

`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMillisecods(4.5))`

Answer (score -1):

You need to understand that [Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) takes a value in milliseconds. So 4.5 is way to small time to even judge that it sleeps.

You can better do something like

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);  
//Change 200 to some value which you want.
```

Also I would suggest you to use Timer instead of Thread.Sleep

```
Timer timer = new Timer(o => Application.DoEvents(), null, 4500, -1);
```

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4500);` sleep for 4.5 sec on each of 220 iterations is not a good idea

Comment: @ASh:- Ooh comon..the time can be changed. The point is that 4.5 millisecond is too less to judge that the thread is sleeping.

Comment: the desired value is 4.5 ms. i don't understand how 4500 ms is better to create a smooth effect

Comment: @ASh:- `the desired value is 4.5 ms.` where is that written?

Comment: in the question `Thread.Sleep(4.5);`. and the problem is not about interval at all: `name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @ASh:- **1.** I have added the System.Threading **2.** My understanding is that 4.5 ms is not going to give any much difference as its a small difference. **3.** I have added the suggestion to use Timer also. Thanks

Comment: 4.5 is way to small, but 4500 is most likely too big. The value is best left to the op where some experiments probably are best to define the right value. Start with 200 ms and keep going up untill you are satisfied.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck:- Indeed that is why I added the comment just below to that! Anyways updated the answer as I think its unnecessarily attracting negtaive attention

Comment: @RahulTripathi, with 200 ms it would be slow, but still better than with 4500

Comment: Just as a note, theoretically 4.5 milliseconds would definitely be noticeable over a large enough period of time.  It looks like the form will be expanding at a rate of ~221px/s.  *Note: this is ignoring the limitations of sleeping with such a small value.